# Cannot Find Style To Remove Line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Working on the following site: http://eptestdev.us/qa
And I cannot figure out how to remove the 1 px gray line above the footer. I've tried getting rid of it from the following classes and have had zero luck:

site
footer
widget
content

I've used Firebug Lite and can't get rid of it. Any help would be supremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the offending css is:

```
#colophon {
     border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
     clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have define in `style.css`

```
#colophon {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    clear: both;
}
```

The `border-top` is the cause of your issue. Delete this row.

Comment: you beat me by 2 seconds.

Comment: This sometimes happens:-)

Answer (score 0):

Look for this in your CSS file:

```
#colophon {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    clear: both;
}
```